# How to copy [OUT] results to a txt document

Tags: printing, copy-as

Hi I am very new to *Mathematica*.

I wanted to ask how can I copy the outputs (`Out`) data from *Mathematica*.

I have results in this format

```
Out[1]    12.9
Out[2]    13.6
Out[3]    7.2
```

I want to copy `12.9; 13.6; 7.2;` to a text document with delimiters

thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). Do you want to use the clipboard (Copy&Paste) or do you want to `Export` into a file directly? Its not very clear what do you need, consider [editing your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), including your code that is generating the output you want to copy.

Comment: Would be easier to work with input instead of output, can you provide the code producing these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
Export["C:\\Temp\\Out.txt",StringJoin[Riffle[Map[ToString[Out[#]]&,{1,2,3}],";"]]]
```

I'd suggest you look up each of [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html), [`StringJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringJoin.html), [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Riffle.html), [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html), [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToString.html) etc to work out what does what.

Comment: Notice that that solution is specific for `Out[1]`,`Out[2]`,`Out[3]`, and will not always work.

Comment: True, but it is what the OP asked and I was hoping it would provide enough meat for some further manual reading.